# Split data frame conditional on factor level summarise based on duplicated values using dplyr

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df<- data.frame(region= c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2"), 
  loc=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","D","E","F"), sp1= 
c("a","a","b","a","e","e","e","e","a","a"), sp2= 
c("b","b","c","b","f","f","f","f","b","b"), inter= 
c("a_b","a_b","b_c","a_b","e_f","e_f","e_f","e_f","a_b","a_b"))
```

I wish to group by `region` to find each the duplicate levels `inter`  among `loc` within the region and then count of how many plots it occurred in.  The output dataframe should appear as follows:

```
df<- data.frame(region= c("1","1","2"), sp1= 
 c("a","e","a"), sp2= 
 c("b","f","b"), inter= 
 c("a_b","e_f","a_b"), freq=c("2","3","2"))
```

I have tried the following:

```
df %>%
group_by(region,inter) %>%
filter(duplicated(inter))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter to groups with more than one row in each `region` and `inter` combo and then use `n_distinct` to count up the number of unique locations.  I included the species variables as groups to keep them in the dataset.

```
df %>%
     group_by(region, sp1, sp2, inter) %>%
     filter(n() > 1) %>%
     summarise( n = n_distinct(loc) )

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   region, sp1, sp2 [?]
  region    sp1    sp2  inter     n
  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1      1      a      b    a_b     2
2      1      e      f    e_f     3
3      2      a      b    a_b     2
```